# Buffer value is all 0's while capturing screenshot on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, rust, screenshot, tauri

I'm trying to capture screenshot of the Foreground-Window on a Windows machine and save it as a PNG file in a Tauri App (for now i'm just focuing on windows OS). but buffer is all 0's resulting in a complete black image.

I feel like there's some issue with the way i'm configuring 'bitmap_info_header'. I'm fairly new to image related works and can't figure out what excatly is going wrong.

```
use image::{ImageBuffer};
use std::mem;
use std::path::Path;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::DWORD;
use winapi::shared::windef::RECT;
use winapi::um::wingdi::{
    BitBlt, GetDIBits, BITMAPINFO, BITMAPINFOHEADER, BI_RGB, DIB_RGB_COLORS, RGBQUAD, SRCCOPY,
};
use winapi::um::winuser::{GetDC, GetForegroundWindow, GetWindowRect, ReleaseDC};

pub fn get_screenshot_buffer() -> SCBufferDetails {
    let hwnd = unsafe { GetForegroundWindow() };

    unsafe {
        let mut rect: RECT = std::mem::zeroed();
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &mut rect);
        let width = rect.right - rect.left;
        let height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        // returns handle to the device context
        let hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        let mut buf: Vec<u32> = vec![0; (width * height) as usize];

        // perform a bit-block transfer from the window's DC to itself (src -> src)
        // effectively captures the screenshot of the window
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        // Prepare the bitmap info header
        let mut bitmap_info_header: BITMAPINFOHEADER = mem::zeroed();
        bitmap_info_header.biSize = mem::size_of::<BITMAPINFOHEADER>() as DWORD;
        bitmap_info_header.biWidth = width;
        bitmap_info_header.biHeight = -height; // Negative height to ensure top-down image
        bitmap_info_header.biPlanes = 1;
        bitmap_info_header.biBitCount = 32;
        bitmap_info_header.biCompression = BI_RGB;

        // Prepare the bitmap info structure
        let mut bitmap_info: BITMAPINFO = mem::zeroed();
        bitmap_info.bmiHeader = bitmap_info_header;

        // retrieve the bitmap information from the window's DC and stores it in the buf buffer.
        GetDIBits(
            hdc,
            null_mut(),
            0,
            height as u32,
            buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut _,
            &mut bitmap_info,
            DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        );
        // release the device context
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        return SCBufferDetails {
            buffer: buf,
            height: height as u32,
            width: width as u32,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In the call to `BitBlt`, should `x1` and `y1` maybe be `rect.left` and `rect.top` respectively?

Comment: User has also asked the question on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/14mbzkv/buffer_value_is_all_0s_while_capturing_screenshot/) and has yet to reply to any of the responses.